# How to run a callback when vue router-link finished navigation

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What I want to do is - the user clicks the router-link - this does not actually do a navigation but just refreshes the page with new data. This is no good for accessibility because the user does not know a navigation happened, but good for performance because full navigation not required.

So I would like some way to solve that problem.

The way I might naively expect to solve the problem is wait for navigation to be over and run a callback, or use a promise and when promise completes run code. The code running when navigation over would put the focus on some element at navigation finished.

I was hoping I could do something obvious like the following

```
<router-link :to="(router) => {
  router.push('/').onComplete(() => {
  code to set focus here
});
  
}"
```

but it doesn't look like that is possible.

How should I solve my problem, as close to this solution as possible please.

Comment: You should use the global navigation hook `afterEach` - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the desired functionality correctly, but I imagine you want to have the user to get some feedback like an animation when you reload the same page with new data. beforeRouteUpdate is a hook especially made for when you reload (update) your route, eventually with new parameters, and would be more appropriate than afterEach I think. Either way, a navigation guard is how to approach this.

Comment: I was afraid it was something like that, if I do afterEach in a particular module it won't pollute the whole router will it. That is to say I am navigating from a reset password link back to the login page - I want to make sure my afterEach only runs between those two pages.

Comment: You have component helpers that only trigger when a certain component loads, so instead of afterEach, use beforeRouteEnter on your home page, or beforeRouteLeave on your password reset view, depending on how you want to split your code. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Comment: @Excalibaard the desired functionality is to focus on a header element when the navigation is finished - the screen reader NVDA reads 'Go back Link' before navigating, and then when navigation done does not read anything because unaware the page has new content. So set content to header it reads that.

Comment: ok so beforeRouteUpdate when I am coming from /password-reset route will be if from === '/password-reset' or something like that. I guess that's enough info to read the docs. thanks

Comment: beforeRouteUpdate only works when the route navigated to is the same, as defined by its matching pattern (ex. `user/3 -> user/4` on a route with path `user/:id`). If you're navigating between `/password-reset` and `/` they're probably different routes, and you'll have to use `beforeRouteEnter` at `'/'` or `beforeRouteLeave` at `'/passsword-reset'`. beforeRouteEnter has the `from` parameter that you can use to check if you originated 'from' password-reset, that's probably where you want your code to focus the header.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might be using the wrong tools for the job. If you aren't actually navigating, there's no good reason to use router link - if you purely want to have the aesthetics of a link, use `<a>`. And if you are just expecting data to be refreshed, don't use `router.push` but simply call the function you want by attaching a listener to the link. If you want to show some kind of loading animation during the data fetching, you could either just set a variable, or use a library like [vue-wait](https://github.com/f/vue-wait)

In your case this could be something like:

```
<a @click="onClick">Link to click</a>

...
data(){
   return {
     isLoading:false
   }
}
methods:{
   async onClick(){
      this.isLoading=true  
      await fetch(...)
      this.isLoading=false
   }
}
```

To answer your original question as well - yes, it's possible to run code when a navigation is finished. There's quite a few ways to do it, but if you want to specifically run code after a router.push, you can do that - router.push is a [promise](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-push). So `router.push(...).then(...).catch()` works as well

Comment: it is actually navigating, it is navigating between the reset password page and the login page, unfortunately since an actual navigation does not happen (by actual navigation I mean that a new http request is sent to the server for a new route and all js, css, html etc. sent again) but just new data being rendered it does not work for a screen reader.

Comment: ok, that's a pretty specific use case - maybe a library like https://github.com/vue-a11y/vue-announcer can help?